# JQuery events not firing for an element in a Dust.js template

Tags: javascript, jquery, dust.js

So I'm using a dust template to render a few elements, and after the template is rendered, the jquery event I have bound to one of the elements doesn't fire.
Dust template:

```
<input type="number" id="numAmounts" value={numAmounts}>
```

Jquery event binding in $(document).ready :

```
$("#numAmounts").on("blur", updateModel);
```

The event doesn't fire at all, anyone have any idea why?

Comment: ids are meant to be unique

Comment: i dont have any other elements with the id numAmounts

Comment: Any info about `updateModel` or where is the listener defined?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Dust.js, but the template may be rendered *after* the DOM ready event fires, so the event handler isn't bound to any elements (it doesn't exist yet). Try `$(document).on('blur', '#numAmounts', updateModel);` instead, and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: you were right good sir!  if you make it an answer ill totally choose you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds as though the Dust.js template is being rendered *after* the DOM ready event fires. That means that when your `$(document).ready()` function is executed no element with an `id` of `numAmounts` exists, and no event handler is bound.

One solution to work around this is to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events):

```
$(document).on('blur', '#numAmounts', updateModel);
```

The basic principle is that the event handler is bound to an element that *does* exist - in this case the `document` itself - and you specify a selector for dynamic elements that will be present inside it that you want to react to that event. Ideally you'd choose something closer to the dynamic elements in the HTML structure than the entire document.

As an alternative solution: From a brief read through the Dust documentation it seems you can pass a callback function to the `render` function that will be executed once the template has been rendered. You could include your static event handler binding in that, and it should be safe to assume that the element will exist at that point. Take a look at the *Callback interface* section of the [Dust.js documentation](http://akdubya.github.com/dustjs/).

Comment: Another solution could be to put the bindings in the $(document).load function